# Test the redirect page

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using Testcafe to test my application. I have a page on which there is a button. When I click the button the page redirects to another page which contains a bunch of images and where a server call happens. Then when the call has been resolved, the page redirects again to another page.

I am trying to test this middle page which shows only for a few seconds.

I want to test that the URL was changed when Page A went to Page B.
I want to test that the page was shown and images were shown.

The problem is that when I automate click on the button on Page A, it goes to Page B and then after a few seconds it goes to Page C and then the test executes and just hangs.

I have tried setting the

```js
await t.setPageLoadTimeout(0)
.wait(200000)
.eval(() => window.location.pathname)
.expect(window.location.pathname)
.contains('/gatheringDetails', 'The response was ok', {timeout: 500});
```

So, I can control the page load timeout to help catch the middle page but it doesn't work.

Can someone help? Please.

Comment: @A Gilani pls, provide the stack trace from the error.

Comment: There is no error, either on console or the browser's console window. I am using chrome.

Comment: Cool. The desired page is located on the iframe or new browser session/tab?

Comment: No it is in the same tab and no iframe... So the sequence is

Page A -> Page B -> Page C

I want to test the Page B but it shows only for few seconds until the backend call completes.

Comment: Dirty hack: 
After PageA is completed, just use navigate to URL of Page B, then add thread sleep. BUT, this is a temporary solution. 
 Does this assertion on the visibility of page B is mandatory?

Comment: yes, i am trying to test the ui of Page b... is there someway i can delay the redirect from Page B to Page C

Comment: @AGilani I don't actually use TestCafe myself, can you verify a presence of an image if you know what image is to be expected?

Comment: Ok. I think the best solution is, to separate this scenario in two tests. Best practice when you write a test is  you must have ONLY one assertion. In your case:
Test 1: page A -> action -> page B -> assert for page B desired content.
Test 2: page A -> action -> page C -> assert for page C desired content.

Comment: You are absolutely right however I have an odd scenario on my hand here where I have to test for Page B but Page B redirects to Page C. I am looking for a way to pause it or at least a way to verify it's contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use a request hook that will listen to page B request and intercept the response. See [Intercepting HTTP Requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/)

Comment: That is the route i took

Answer (score 0):

So i used [Intercepting HTTP Requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/) and introduce a delay in response so i can stay on the page B longer to test the visuals on it.

Comment: great job! But i am a  little bit curious on how you have delayed the response.

Comment: before returning response add a delay using timeout

Comment: @AGilani - would you mind sharing how exactly you added the delay?